Gamescope Errors with RADV
i have just fresh installed arch and i cannot get gamescope to open. if it is run outside of GDM it gives this error (at end of post). I have reinstalled all of the packages and cannot find any information online
No CAP_SYS_NICE, falling back to regular-priority compute and threads.
Performance will be affected.
vulkan: selecting physical device 'AMD Radeon RX 570 Series (RADV POLARIS10)': queue family 1 (general queue family 0)
vulkan: physical device does not support DRM format modifiers
wlserver: [backend/headless/backend.c:67] Creating headless backend
wlserver: [libseat] [libseat/backend/seatd.c:64] Could not connect to socket /run/seatd.sock: No such file or directory
wlserver: [libseat] [libseat/libseat.c:76] Backend 'seatd' failed to open seat, skipping
wlserver: [libseat] [libseat/libseat.c:73] Seat opened with backend 'logind'
wlserver: [backend/session/session.c:108] Successfully loaded libseat session
drm: opening DRM node '/dev/dri/card1'
drm: Connector HDMI-A-1 -> BNQ - BenQ GL2460
drm: [colorimetry]: EDID with colorimetry detected. Using it
drm: [colorimetry]: r 0.644531 0.332031
drm: [colorimetry]: g 0.315430 0.619141
drm: [colorimetry]: b 0.151367 0.065430
drm: [colorimetry]: w 0.313477 0.329102
drm: Connector HDMI-A-1 -> BNQ - BenQ GL2460
drm: [colorimetry]: EDID with colorimetry detected. Using it
drm: [colorimetry]: r 0.644531 0.332031
drm: [colorimetry]: g 0.315430 0.619141
drm: [colorimetry]: b 0.151367 0.065430
drm: [colorimetry]: w 0.313477 0.329102
drm: Connectors:
drm:   DVI-D-1 (disconnected)
drm:   HDMI-A-1 (connected)
drm:   DP-3 (disconnected)
drm:   DP-2 (disconnected)
drm:   DP-1 (disconnected)
drm: selecting connector HDMI-A-1
drm: selecting mode 1920x1080@60Hz
vulkan: supported DRM formats for sampling usage:
vulkan:   AR24 (0x34325241)
vulkan:   XR24 (0x34325258)
vulkan:   AB24 (0x34324241)
vulkan:   XB24 (0x34324258)
vulkan:   RG16 (0x36314752)
vulkan:   NV12 (0x3231564E)
vulkan:   AB4H (0x48344241)
vulkan:   XB4H (0x48344258)
vulkan:   AB48 (0x38344241)
vulkan:   XB48 (0x38344258)
vulkan:   AB30 (0x30334241)
vulkan:   XB30 (0x30334258)
vulkan:   AR30 (0x30335241)
vulkan:   XR30 (0x30335258)
drm: drmModeAddFB2 failed: Invalid argument
drm: drmModeAddFB2 failed: Invalid argument
drm: drmModeAddFB2 failed: Invalid argument
drm: drmModeAddFB2 failed: Invalid argument
wlserver: Using explicit sync when available
wlserver: Running compositor on wayland display 'gamescope-0'
wlserver: [backend/headless/backend.c:17] Starting headless backend
wlserver: [backend/libinput/backend.c:88] Starting libinput backend
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Power Button [0:1]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Power Button [0:1]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Corsair CORSAIR K57 RGB Wireless Gaming Keyboard [6940:7022]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding HDP Webcam USB: HDP Webcam USB [3141:25451]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Logitech Gaming Mouse G402 [1133:49278]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Logitech Gaming Mouse G402 Keyboard [1133:49278]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Corsair CORSAIR Slipstream Multi-Device Receiver Keyboard [6940:2626]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/events.c:69] Adding Corsair CORSAIR Slipstream Multi-Device Receiver [6940:2626]
wlserver: [backend/libinput/backend.c:127] libinput successfully initialized
wlserver: Successfully initialized libei for input emulation!
wlserver: [xwayland/server.c:107] Starting Xwayland on :2
wlserver: [types/wlr_compositor.c:771] New wlr_surface 0x555b6690ee80 (res 0x555b66a4d2f0)
wlserver: [xwayland/server.c:272] Xserver is ready
pipewire: stream state changed: connecting
pipewire: stream state changed: paused
pipewire: stream available on node ID: 104
xwm: Embedded, no cursor set. Using left_ptr by default.
vblank: Using timerfd.
xwm: execvp failed: No such file or directory
gamescope: children shut down!
(EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe

